# How to create a windows authentication user on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssis

I would like to connect to the company's SQL Server 2014, where I am working at, with my computer using windows authentication. I need this to deploy from my machine SSIS packages, without having to access remotely our server's machine.

I have been trying to add a login with my computer name plus my user as MY_COMPUTER\USER, but I keep getting an error, which tells me the it wasn't able to find the domain of my computer.

So, how can I connect my computer to our SQL Server using a windows authentication?

Comment: The login should be added as DOMAIN_NAME\USER_NAME

Comment: Indeed, that is what I have been trying to do, but to no avail. Do I have to change my computer name?

Comment: Is your computer joined to domain? Can you create a SQL login and access the server via SSMS using that SQL login?

Comment: Yes, I can access the domain and I have been working on our server using a SQL Login.

Comment: Can you connect the server using Windows Authentication in SSMS? (not try to deploy SSIS for now, just to connect to see databases, tables, etc.). Also run "echo %USERDNSDOMAIN%" and "echo %USERDOMAIN%" on your computer and on your server using command prompt.

Comment: check if you do not  access on server and your machine and  server machine are in same domain ..

Comment: @Anton No, I can only access it using a SQL Account, unless I use remote access.

Comment: Hello @sandeeprawat I do have access to the server, but I don't think my computer is in the same domain. How can I add?

Comment: Thanks for the information guys. I just figured it out. We do have a windows network domain joined with out SQL Server. I had already created a user for my computer on our windows network, but when I was logging in, I wasn't joining as the new user. Sometimes the smaller things are so hard to look at.

Your comments were very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE LOGIN [DomainName\Username] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
```

Your local computer name isn't part of this at all.  DomainName is the name of the windows network domain name that your SQL server would be joined to in this case. If your SQL server is not joined to a domain then that is a different scenario and I can't test but I would think you would use the computer name of the SQL Server in place of domain name and then the name of the local user....

Anyway, do you know your Domain Name?

DomainName\Username

If not joined to a domain try

SqlServerComputername\Username

Comment: Thanks for the information Matt. I just figured it out. We do have a windows network domain joined with out SQL Server. I had already created a user for my computer on our windows network, but when I was logging in, I wasn't joining as the new user. Sometimes the smaller things are so hard to look at.

Answer (score 0):

We have a windows network domain joined with our SQL Server. I had already created a user for my computer on our windows network, but I wasn't logging in using the new user.